# When to use grails <g:if test> vs angular ng-if ?

Tags: angularjs, grails

As far as I know, they both hide/show DOM elements depending on whether a condition is being met. Is there a rule or guideline for using one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very major difference in both of these.

1. The first one is `<g:if>` tag which is a Grails/GSP tag and is executed on the server for rendering of the contents in the `<g:if>...</g:if>` block if the test condition is passed.

Example- Suppose if you send some data over the server or retrieve the data from the server then you can use the `<g:if>` tag to check for some condition and filter out the data as per your need on server only. So over all in this case the data/DOM elements, if filtered by `<g:if>` won't reach the client side.

2. The second one is `ng-if` which is angular js code and is executed on the client side and can be used to serve the dynamic nature of your application.

Example - In this case we get all the data/DOM elements from the server and on the client side due to filtering by `ng-if` the filtered data/DOM elements remains and the other data/DOM elements gets deleted.

You can even use both of them together depending on your need.

Answer (score 1):

`<g:if>` does not include the containing HTML into the output of your server response.  `ng-if` is client side only (more or less just hides it in the browser, most likely not handled or complete if used without JS).  you can mix both.  it depends, if you need the HTML to be there (e.g. for responses to non-JS clients).

Comment: `ng-if` does not hide DOM elements. It removes the element from the DOM. When condition satisfied it adds it back to the DOM in a `$digest` cycle. However, `ng-show` and `ng-hide` toggles showing and hiding without removing then from DOM.

Comment: @dmahapatro removing it from the dom and keeping it safe in my browsers ram counts as hiding in my world ;)  i didn't want to imply a `display:none` or alike.